# Ler 15 elementos em uma matriz A tipo vetor. Criar matriz B seja a fatorial do elemento correspondente da matriz A

Tags: c

**Ler 15 elementos em uma matriz A tipo vetor. Criar uma matriz B de mesma dimensão, sendo que Cada elemento da matriz B seja a fatorial do elemento correspondente da matriz A. Exibir os elementos da matriz B ordenados de forma crescente.**

**Boa Tarde, alguém poderia me ajudar. Eu estou em duvida de como eu posso fazer para que o programa exiba em ordem crescente. Obrigado desde já!!**

insira o código aqui

```
 //Ex 3 Fatorial
 #include <stdio.h>

int main (){

int fat[12],i,vet[12];

for (i=0; i<12; i++)
{
printf("Digite um numero:\n");
scanf ("%d",&vet[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    for (fat[i] = 1; vet[i] > 1; vet[i]--) {
        fat[i] *= vet[i];
    }
    {
        printf ("\n\n");
    }
    printf("%d", fat[i]);
}   

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ordene o array em ordem crescente. Existem muitos métodos de ordenação, veja: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o